# Unsure why changes to a factory property are not being pushed to the page

Tags: angularjs

This is a simplistic example of a problem I am having.  I am clearly missing something in my understanding of Angular.

A Plunker is here:  http://plnkr.co/edit/VLqA22dDTgk5PyPlCOGH?p=preview

And a copy-paste of the pertinent bits below:

```
<div ng-controller="myController"> 
  <div>message: <label ng-model="message"></label></div>
  <div></div><button ng-click="start()">Get Message</button></div>
</div>

var app = angular.module("app", []);  
  app.service('GetMessage', function() {
    var message;
    var start = function () {
      this.message = 'Hello World';
    };  
    return {
      message: this.message,
      start: start
    }
  });

app.controller('myController', function ($scope, GetMessage) {    
  $scope.message = GetMessage.message;
  $scope.start = function () {
    GetMessage.start();
    console.warn('started..');
  };
});
```

I would expect that the label directive would be 2-way bound to the factory's message property, so that when the start() function is called and the message is updated, that the page would be too.

To update the label in this way, do I need to broadcast an event to $rootScope, listen for it in the controller, and then update the label? It seems a very manual way of doing it.. surely there is a better way.

Thank you.

Comment: You forgot to bootstrap your app in the plunker, as @ivarni mentioned. For example: `<html ng-app="app">` Not sure if copy paste error or not.

Comment: Thanks, yes that was an error for this example, cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are currently using a primitive data type, which means the following line will copy the value into a new variable:

```
$scope.message = GetMessage.message;
```

Updating one will not affect the other.

An easy solution is to use an object instead:

```
var message = { value: '' };

var start = function() {
  message.value = 'Hello World';
};
```

And:

```
$scope.message = GetMessage.message;
```

Now the reference to the object would be copied into a new variable instead and both would refer to the same object.

Another issue is that you are using `ngModel` on a label to display the value, which will not work. `ngModel` is normally used on input, select and textarea elements.

You can instead use `ng-bind`:

```
<label ng-bind="message.value"></label>
```

Or the less verbose shortcut:

```
<label>{{message.value}}</label>
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/rUgN94DAIOfQGI8tr9kl?p=preview

If you prefer to keep using primtive values you need to handle it another way. For example by using events like you mentioned. Another solution is to register a watcher to watch for changes and update the scope variable:

```
app.controller('myController', function($scope, GetMessage) {

  var watchExpression = function() {
    return GetMessage.message;
  };

  var listener = function(newValue, oldValue) {
    if (newValue === oldValue) return;
    $scope.message = newValue;
  }

  $scope.$watch(watchExpression, listener);

  $scope.start = function() {
    GetMessage.start();
    console.warn('started..');
  };
});
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/klSl1DCUlQI3Z5ih16sq?p=preview

Comment: he also forgot the `ng-app` directive. It's in your plnkr but you might want to mention it in the answer as well.

Comment: Ahh, the primitive data types - I see now. Thank you!  It's also good to see how it could be done with $watch, I shall refer to that in the future should I need it. Thanks again.

Comment: I thought I'd reflect on this 10 months later. A good overview of prototypal inheritance in Angular can be found here: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes